# Incorrect offset in element info array

Tags: oracle-spatial

I have a table with these columns
circle_id  number, circle geometry  sdo geometry, latitude   varchar2,   longitude varchar2.

I want to check overlapping between shapes, by giving my lat and long in input if these points are overlapping with any shape in table then it should show me result (overplapping).

This is what I have tried.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prc_overlap ( p_lati in varchar2,
                                      p_longi IN VARCHAR2,
                                      pcursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR, ) AS
 coords      mdsys.sdo_ordinate_array := mdsys.sdo_ordinate_array();
pcount      NUMBER;
plng        NUMBER;
plat        NUMBER;
 v_ploygon   sdo_geometry;
v_cur_lat   SYS_REFCURSOR;
v_cur_lon   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
OPEN v_cur_lat FOR SELECT
                       *
                   FROM
TABLE ( func_string_to_table(p_lati, ',') );

OPEN v_cur_lon FOR SELECT
                      *
FROM
                      TABLE ( func_string_to_table(p_longi, ',') );-- func string to table is just converting comma separated values into column.

FETCH v_cur_lat INTO plat;
FETCH v_cur_lon INTO plng;
pcount := 1;
WHILE v_cur_lat%found AND v_cur_lon%found LOOP
    coords.extend();
    coords(pcount) := plat;
    coords.extend();
    pcount := pcount + 1;
    coords(pcount) := plng;
 pcount := pcount + 1;
    FETCH v_cur_lat INTO plat;
    FETCH v_cur_lon INTO plng;
END LOOP;
v_ploygon := mdsys.sdo_geometry(2003 -- 2D Polygon

, 4326 -- WGS84, the typical GPS coordinate system

, NULL -- sdo_point_type, should be NULL if sdo_ordinate_array specified

, mdsys.sdo_elem_info_array(1     -- First ordinate position within ordinate array

, 1003 -- Exterior polygon

, 1    -- All polygon points are specified in the ordinate array

), coords);
pcount := 0;
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
INTO pcount
FROM
(
        SELECT
            sdo_geom.relate(sd_geo, 'OVERLAPBDYINTERSECT', v_ploygon, 0.001) AS result
        FROM
            test_circle
        WHERE
            sdo_geom.relate(sd_geo, 'OVERLAPBDYINTERSECT', v_ploygon, 0.0001) = 'TRUE'
    );
IF pcount > 0 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('CAN NOT ENTER THIS GEOMETRY BECAUSE OF OVERLAPPING');
```

when I tried to run this, it gives me this error
[image]

Comment: Error messages should always be included in the body of the Question as text. Images are not legible on all devices and cannot be searched.

Comment: I tried running your syntax, but I gave up. It has basic errors (commas where there should be none) and is badly formatted making it hard to read. It also has "*" in various places that look like error markers. So this looks like some execution result you captured. Please share the original code.

Comment: Your need is also not clear. You need to show your table definitions and some sample data, so we can try and understand that it is you want to achieve

Comment: This is the original code, and it is working fine except it gives this error of incorrect info array.

Comment: my table contains circle_id, circle_geometry columns. the circle geometry column is of sdo_geo data type. my sample data is  (p_lat = '77.22,79.90'    ,  p_longi = '-33,-34.56')